# Windows 8 removes grub2 as default bootloader

Tags: linux, windows-8, debian, bootloader, grub2

I have a dualboot setup where I keep Linux distros in separated partitions on one SSD, and my Windows drive on another. Recently, I had to wipe my Windows drive and reinstall Windows, which was great and all, however it ended up removing grub2 as a default bootloader.

I can mount and access the partitions on Linux drive, however I can't boot up grub2 in order to actually run said partitions.

How would I go about repairing this without having to boot up a LiveCD and reinstalling grub2, preferably via CMD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use free tools such as [this](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).. although cmd might work with great effort its a ms tool it will only favor windows e.g if you want to add another **windows** installation to the boot-loader (btw i have only witnessed cmd doing that using bootrec.exe in recovery mode).

Comment: in that case would it be faster to just reinstall grub2

Comment: good luck with that.